# How to extract the text between <a></a>

Tags: jquery, text, tags, extract

I must use jQuery for first time....

```
<a class="Tag Resource" href="http://localhost/" 
resource="http://localres/" property="prop">test</a>
```

I've tried to extract the text using `var = $('a').find('Tag Resource').text();` and `var = $('a').find('Tag Resource').html();` but it doesn't work.  I need "test" as plain text.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn css selectors and/or read http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/11/how-to-get-anything-you-want-part-1 and http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/12/how-to-get-anything-you-want-part-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
var t = $("a.Tag.Resource").text();
```

meaning a tags that have **both** the `Tag` and `Resource` classes. The find() method is for searching subtrees of elements.

Comment: This doesn't get the text for the specific tag Sirakov is looking for. The one with a class of "Tag Reference".

Comment: var t = $("a").text(); - this give me not the text

Answer (score 5):

Here you go ([live demo](http://jsbin.com/eyojo)):

```
$(document).ready(
  function (){ 
    alert(  $('a.Tag.Resource').html()  );  
});
```

Your issue is either that you wanted one class but used a space so it became two; or that when referring to classes with a jquery selector, you need to prefix them with a period.

In any case, the above code will help. If you really just wanted one class, change it to `$('a.Tag-Resource')...`

Comment: Haven't seen jsbin before, nice tool! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the syntax of your find expression.

**Update**: In fact, you don't want find at all, you want filter.
Find will only select descendants of the a elements, rather than the elements themselves.

I've tested the example line below.

From the example [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#classclass), it looks like you want

```
var text = $('a').filter('.Tag.Resource').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "";
$("a").each(function(){
  text += $(this).html() + " " + $(this).attr("resource");
});
alert(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have class names with spaces in.
You've added 2 classes "Tag" and"Resource" to the a tag and your find selectory won't find that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, class names can be repeated on a page, and spaces indicate two classes applied to an element.  You are not guaranteed that a single element will have that class, so .text() may return the **combined text** of all matched elements.

```
$(".Tag.Resource").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to use JQuery...

```
var text, links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
   if (links[i].className == 'Tag Resource') {
      text = links[i].innerText;
      break;
   }
}
alert(text);
```